# How to approach this kind of task about kinetic energy?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinetic-theory

The bullet with mass $$m_{ball}=0.2 kg$$ travels with speed $$v=2 \frac{m}{s}$$ and hits Plasticine sphere with mass $$m_{sphere}=2.5 kg$$ and get stuck. I need to find the amount of heat ejected. How to approach this task? Probably it's about kinetic energy transforming to heat; and the law of conservation of momentum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The velocity of the system after collision is
$$
V=\frac{m_b}{m_b+m_s}v_b
$$

The lost of kinetic energy can be assumed as the ejected heat in question,
\begin{align}
\Delta KE &= m_b v_b^2 /2 -  (m_b+m_s)V^2 /2\\
          &=  m_b v_b^2 /2 - \frac{m_b^2}{m_b+m_s}v_b^2 /2\\
          &= m_b v_b^2/2 \left(1-\frac{m_b}{m_b+m_s} \right)\\
          &=  \frac{m_b m_s}{m_b+m_s}v_b^2/2 \\
\end{align}